# How to get progress update every 3 seconds in C++ in long computation

Tags: c++

I have a program that runs a computation for 10+ hours. It's an entry-by-entry based task that reads a file line by line and computes on the input. At the moment it stays silent for 10 hours before spitting out a "Time elapsed: xxx minutes" message.

I would like to get updates as I go, but I would also like to over-engineer the problem such that I get updates at regular intervals. Clearly I can do some kind of

```
if (++tasks_processed % 100000 == 0)
    cout << tasks_processed << " entries processed...\n";
```

But I expect I may improve my algorithms in the near future or simple advances in processor/disk speeds will cause my program to be spamming out a dozen of these per second in 2-3 year's time. So instead I want to be able to future proof my reporting intervals.

Now the alternative is to have some `chrono` based solution where I say

```
high_resolution_clock::time_point t_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

while (...) {
    processing...

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t_now = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(t_now - t_start).count();
    if (duration >=3)
        cout << tasks_processed << " entries processed...\n";
}
```

But this adds a lot of overhead to a tight loop. Are there any other facilities I could make use of to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Have one thread set a global atomic variable and a second thread that publishes progress every 3 seconds?

Comment: have hybride, check clocks every 100 000th cycle, if enough time has passed, report.

Comment: Register a callback to be invoked every 3 seconds for the O/S to notify you. The callback is a thread that you create in your own process space that does its computation quickly when triggered. That work has to get done under 3 seconds. It runs parallel to the O/S tick counter.

Comment: Are there simple standard library features that would allow me to easily set aside an asynchronous thread for doing this kind of timing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this self explanatory pseudo code as a solution

```
void LongComputation(std::atomic<bool>& running, std::atomic<float>& progress)
{
    // do long computation
    while (running)
    {

        //update progress 
    }
}

void ProgressCounter(std::atomic<bool>& running, std::atomic<float>& progress)
{
    while (running)
    {
        std::cout << progress << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    }
}

int main() {

    std::atomic<bool> running{true};
    std::atomic<float> progress{0};

    std::thread t1([&running, &progress]() { LongComputation(running, progress); });
    std::thread t2([&running, &progress]() { ProgressCounter(running, progress); });

    //simulating GUI loop 
    while (!getch())
    {

    }

    running = false;
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Is there some construction that would allow me to spawn an asynchronous thread from `LongComputation` so I don't have to refactor my code to wrap a master caller over both the computation and the progress counter?

Comment: @shians: You can spawn new worker threads from the main computational thread, but just pass the reference variables ( running and progress) to them as well so that you can exit cleanly from any thread when the GUI desires to terminate the program.

Comment: There is a data race on `running`, switch to atomics